# Introducir un input en html para verificación

Tags: html

me gustaría introducir un input en mi formulario, para verificacion, el caso es que no doy con el elemento html para darle este estilo, me refiero concretamente, a un input que dentro del mismo tenga subdivisiones entre dígitos, ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="es">
    <head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <title>Formulario Login - Cliente</title>
     </head>
     <body>
     <form name="" id="" action="" method="POST" class="form" onsubmit="">
     <h2>INICIAR SESIÓN</h2>
     <input type="text" placeholder="&#128272; Usuario" name="email" required>
     <input type="password" placeholder="&#128272; Contraseña" name="password" required>
     <div align="center">
     <input type="submit" value="Iniciar sesión">
     </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      <title>Ejemplo 1</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form action="#">
      Valor 1 <input id="deshabilitado" disabled type="text" />
      <p>Selecciona la opción 2 para habilitar</p>
      <select name="" id="opciones">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
      </select>
    </form>
    <script>
        let opcion = document.getElementById("opciones")
        let caja   = document.getElementById("deshabilitado")
        
        opcion.addEventListener("change", () => {
          let elementoElegido = opcion.options[opcion.selectedIndex].value
          if (elementoElegido === "2") {
            caja.disabled = false
          } else {
            caja.disabled = true
          } 
        })
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).